# What is the possibility that at least one digit will not show up in a 20-digit "code"?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

> A "code" is composed of 20 digits (numbers from 0 to 9), and we want to choose a number randomly. What is the possibility that at least one digit will not show up in the code?

What I did:
We have $10^{20}$ possibilities. 
Now, I want to choose 9 numbers out of the ten, and choose them randomly, so the possibility is:

$\frac{10\cdot9^{20}}{10^{20}} = \frac{9^{20}}{10^{19}}$

But when I put this in the calculator, I get $1.25\dots$ I thought maybe I need a more precise calculator, but even calculators I found in google returns the same answer.

The possibility isn't supposed to be above 1. What is the problem here?

Comment: You're counting a lot of things twice. For example, you are counting the number 11111111111111111111 as "no twos", "no threes", "no fours" and so on.

Comment: Probability of a number not being $n$ is $9\over10$. Possibility in a 20-digit sequence is $\left({9\over10}\right)^{20}=0.12157...$

Comment: It's not your calculator.  $9^{20} = 1.215\ldots  \times 10^{19} > 10^{19}$.

Comment: This seems like a variant of the coupon collector's problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For any *given* digit, the probability the "code" does not contain that digit is indeed $(9/10)^{20}$. But computing the probability that *any one* of the ten digits is missing requires the inclusion/exclusion principle.

- Add $10×(9/10)^{20}$, like you did, for the probability that one digit is missing.
- Subtract $45×(8/10)^{20}$ for the probability that *two* digits are missing. 45 is the number of ways to choose two digits to omit.
- Add $120×(7/10)^{20}$ for the probability that three digits are missing. Again, 120 is the number of ways to omit three digits.
- Continue until adding $10×(1/10)^{20}$ for the probability that nine digits are missing.

The final, correct answer is $0.785262\dots$

Comment: Doesn't the wording "..... a $certain$ digit will not show up ..." imply that a particular digit doesn't show up irrespective of other digits being present or absent ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Meaning clarified.

Comment: Was that clarified by OP ??

Comment: @trueblueanil That was what the OP meant, as evidenced by the other comments.

Comment: I don't think it is right to edit OP's $question$. We can ask for clarifications, or mention that it is our interpretation.

Comment: Well the answer was actually "a certain", but I think you answered for both "at least" and "a certain". So I got the other one for a bonus. Thanks :)

Comment: @sheldonzy "A certain" digit means that digit is given beforehand. On a strict reading, the probability of that not occuring is indeed $(9/10)^{20}$. But since your calculations and the comments favoured the "at least one" interpretation, I went for that.